# Wordpress: If is_page() and not is_front_page()

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Is there a way, in WordPress, to test if is a page and is not the front page. When I use the following PHP if logic it fails to give me the output I hoped.

```
<?php if( !is_front_page() && is_page() ) : ?>
     <!-- THEN OUTPUT THIS HTML -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: If you ever need help with more WordPress specific questions, feel free to ask them at the [WordPress Deveopment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this 
`

```
global $post;

 if( !is_front_page() && $post->post_type=='page' ) : ?>

 <!-- THEN OUTPUT THIS HTML -->
```

`